# CocosSharp + Xamarin.forms + Carousel Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, cocossharp

I'm working on game in Xamarin.forms. I'm using CocosSharp as my graphic engine and it is great, but I have an question. My game is suppose to have 3 diffrent tabs/pages, so I used an Carousel Pages to do that. And now my question can I have multiple CCScenes on diffrent pages or can I use one CCScane but places CCLayers on those Pages?
I will be gratefull for all responses